# SQL query to find which customer bought Glass or at least a Doll

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below customer table

[image: Original teable]

Below is my code

```
select Cust_ID, Item_ID from custTable where Item_ID = (
Case 
when Item_ID in ('Doll','Glass') then 'Glass'
else 'Doll'
End )
```

expected result is

[image: Final result]

How do i get the expected result table, I need to change my where statement but not sure how i can use if else in the where, can someone direct me in the correct direction please.

Comment: Considering that all your customers bought glass or a doll, why are all the rows not displayed? I don't understand your logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you group your data by customers then you can select the alphabetically MAX (highest) `item_id` for each one.

```
select Cust_ID, max(Item_ID)
from custTable 
where Item_ID in ('Doll', 'Glass')
group by Cust_ID
```